# AJAX not working But normal form Submit does

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

can anybody see why this ajax will not post the required data,

It still sucseeds and alerts , but no data is sent.

A normal ('#formid').submit will work , but obviously page refreshes

I require a non refresh. it is for a favorites button

But i cant understand why the data is not being sent.

the mysql and php is fine on the receiving page and works when i do a normal submit,

but when i try the ajax, it fails to send any data???

```
<form id='addfaveform' type='submit' action='favaddDB.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 

<input id='ListID2' type='hidden' name='listID2' value='' ></input>             

<input id='UID2' type='hidden' name='UID2' value='' ></input>       

<input id='accountname' type='hidden' name='accountname' value='' ></input>     

</form>

<script>

function faveadd(fid){
var listingid="favicon["+fid+"]"

var variable_UID = undefined;
var variable_listID = undefined;
var variable_accountname = undefined;


var variable_UID = document.getElementById(listingid).getAttribute("data-variable-uid2");
var variable_listID = document.getElementById(listingid).getAttribute("data-variable-listID2");
var variable_accountname = document.getElementById(listingid).getAttribute("data-variable-accountname2");

// change input variables to post to view listing page

document.getElementById("UID2").value = variable_UID;   
document.getElementById("ListID2").value = variable_listID; 
document.getElementById("accountname").value = variable_accountname;

//document.getElementById("addfaveform").submit();



          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'favaddDB.php',
            data: $('addfaveform').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });


};
```

Comment: function is called from an onclick event elsewhere. also working

Comment: oops... missed the # ... really sorry.. wasted any1's time.

Comment: This is a typo ? `$('addfaveform').serialize(),`

Comment: Open the developer console. What do you see? If unsure what is happening add breakpoints in the `sources` tab.

Comment: Delete if poss, thanks

Comment: You should have a delete question option under the tags.

Answer (score 0):

`php` cannot catch data because you did not give the `ajax` data a name. for example:

`PHP` code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['data_name'])){
        //Do somthing
    }
?>
```

So, `ajax` call should be like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'favaddDB.php',
    data: {'data_name': $('addfaveform').serialize()},
    success: function () {
        alert('form was submitted');
    }
});
```

I think this will fix your problem.